# how to set custom function to cookie in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, cookie, php-7

How to set **uniqid** in cookie in Magento2?

```
 public function generateVisitorId()
    {
         $visitorId = $this->_checkoutSession->get('visitor_id');              
        if (!$visitorId) {
            $visitorId = uniqid();
         $this->_checkoutSession->set('visitor_id', $visitorId, $this->getExpiryTime(), '/');        
        }
        return $visitorId;
    }
```

But id returning only  `empty array` .If any changes in code....If anyone knows please expain me....

Comment: Also trying  $this->_cookieManager->setCookie('visitor_id', $visitorId, $this->getExpiryTime(), '/');

Comment: But its returning  Call to protected method Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::setCookie() Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the code below,

```
  <?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PublicCookieMetadata;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;


class Classname extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
        SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
        )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;

        $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->_cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->_sessionManager = $sessionManager;


        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $seller_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('seller_id');



        $this->registry->register('seller_id',$seller_id);


        //$this->deleteCookie(); this is for delete the cookie
        $this->setCookie();
        return true    
    }


    public function deleteCookie()
    {

        $duration = '86400';

        $this->_cookieManager->deleteCookie(
            'seller_id',
            $this->_cookieMetadataFactory
                ->createCookieMetadata()
                ->setPath($this->_sessionManager->getCookiePath())
                ->setDomain($this->_sessionManager->getCookieDomain())
        );
        return true;

    }

    public function setCookie()
    {

         $duration = '86400';

         $metadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setDuration($duration)
            ->setPath($this->_sessionManager->getCookiePath())
            ->setDomain($this->_sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

        $this->_cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
            'seller_id',
            $this->getSellerId(),
            $metadata
        );

        return true;

    }



    public function getSellerName()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('seller_id');
    }


}
```

Comment: not working while FPC is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the class  `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;`

and the function `setPublicCookie()` to set a cookie